# Download an article with unicode title from Wikipedia using wget in xml format

Tags: windows, wget, wikipedia

I am currently downloading the XML from Wikipedia for individual articles. For this I use wget with the following call format

```
https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Export/?title=Special:Export&pages=**<page>**&curonly=1&templates=1&action=submit
```

This also works, but I have problems with e.g. Cyrillic characters. They are encoded for the page (a lot of %). But this does not seem to work. I always get back only the schema definition. If I enter the address (see above) in the browser it works.
I have already tried with --remote-encoding=UTF-8 . It affects windows!

Comment: does using double quotes around url help?

Comment: tried already double and single qoutes -> the same

Comment: the error message is  scheme missing

Comment: Please provide a more concrete / reproduceable example. Which exact URL and please point out where the encoding fails

Comment: I have solved the problem in the meantime. You have to set --local-encoding=UTF8 AND --remote-encoding=UTF8. then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not sufficient to set the encoding for the target server via

```
 --remote-encoding=UTF8
```

to specify.
For the input it is also mandatory to do this.

```
--local-encoding=UTF8
```

Then wget does not replace it with the % replacement. Otherwise wget assumes ASCII encoding and uses % replacement.

Comment: a small typo. Should be utf-8 instead of utf8